# apache proxypass in VirtualHost - shouldn't it override main?

Tags: apache-2.2

This is a trivialised example highlighting my situation:

```
ProxyPass /google/ http://www.google.com/
ProxyPassReverse /google/ http://www.google.com/

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:82>
   ProxyPass /google/ http://www.yahoo.com/
   ProxyPassReverse /google/ http://www.yahoo.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

In this case a request "http://127.0.0.1:82/google/" will try to go to http://www.google.com

I have also found that a ProxyPass defined in main will take precedence over actual directories available in a vhost - eg if in above instead of the VirtualHost having ProxyPass rules its DocumentRoot contained a directory named "google" the Proxy would still be in effect.

Per the apache docs, I had been led to believe any "main" definition would be overridden by a VirtualHost able to satisfy the request.

Comment: In your example you don't list a ServerName or ServerAlias for the VirtualHost and you're using the loopback address... So are you using http://127.0.0.1/google/ to hit it or using http://hostname/google/ where hostname resolves to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I should have specified - the config is IP based virtualhosting so name becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, You are right. I don't know if this would be right, but you may remedy it by including the default proxy options to [VirtualHost *default*] section (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default) like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        ServerName noneset
        DocumentRoot /dev/null
        ProxyPass /google/ http://www.google.com/
        ProxyPassReverse /google/ http://www.google.com/
<VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ProxyPass /google/ http://www.yahoo.com/
        ProxyPassReverse /google/ http://www.yahoo.com/

</VirtualHost>

<Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Comment: Thanks - seems ProxyPass just isn't over-ridable at all. I've ended up rewriting all my ProxyPass rules as RewriteRule [P] which does the same job but also allows other RewriteRules etc to be processed instead of the ProxyPass being run first & only.